# No disk drive after moving Ubuntu to windows 7 and disabled raid 0 rom

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, raid-0, hard-drive-failure

This morning I used my hp envy ultrabook(win7) and left locked for 1 hour. When I came back it gave me a dll problem. Then I tried to restart system and it gave BSOD. I could not make recovery and system restore to work and decided to boot.

When I tried to boot there were no hard disks on the win7 install screen. Then I decided to install ubuntu. I installed ubuntu and there were no problems then I formatted all disks and installed win7.

However, after completing installation, win7 restarted system and intel option rom screen (similar to the following) appeared:

[image: 1]

I applied the answer in this link http://communities.intel.com/thread/32351 now I have only 50gb partition and I even cannot use that.

The partition that I installed win7 disappeared and when I start my system is says there is no os on the hard disk.

Could you please help me to recover Raid section and make appear lost disk partitions again?

Comment: how can I access this intel option rom screen again?

Comment: It's not clear what you did. For example, did you reset the disks to non-RAID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the steps I used to rebuild a FAILED array on my machine. Note that mine was FAILED and not DISABLED so it may be different. If anyone has experience with DISABLED arrays you should listen to them first.

It is possible to rebuild your array without loosing any of your data.

1. Take note of your array settings. The photo you have provided here should do.
2. Reset all disks from the array to be Non-RAID disks. It will warn that your data will be lost, but only the RAID data (not all disk data) will be lost.
3. Create a new array with the exact same settings as the old array (EXACT SAME SETTINGS!). It will again warn about lost data, disregard and keep moving.

**You will need to be able to boot into SOMETHING from here. Time for a Live CD or second windows bootable drive.**

4. Download a copy of Test Disk from http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk
5. Follow the instructions here: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step (they may be a bit confusing so read slowly and carefully. If you mess this up, there's no guarantees)

TestDisk will find the old RAID data (from before you recreated the array in step 2 above) and recreate the layout. This method has worked for me several times.

Comment: I should also note that I'm not sure if what you did as part of the Intel thread will affect my solution above.